# Adding a rel="me" attribute with jekyll-target-blank

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions, mastodon

Mastodon has a [link verification](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/user/profile/#verification) service that requires a `<a href="https://example.social/username" rel="me">` attribute to be added to the website.

I am using the [al-folio](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio) theme for Jekyll, which includes the [jekyll-target-blank](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank) plugin as a part of a [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll) build. The plugin "automatically adds a `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute to all external links in Jekyll's content".

As a result, my link to my Mastodon profile is built with the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute. What is the best way to replace this single tag’s attribute with the `rel="me"` attribute? Is there an option in jekyll-target-blank or something I should do during or after the build with GitHub Pages?

Comment: Looks like the plugin [stomps any existing rel value](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank/blob/f6fb51a819a465127dabc9fadfc08f8dacfe8ab4/lib/jekyll-target-blank.rb#L155). You're not the [only person to notice](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank/issues/54) this, and there's an [open PR](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank/pull/59) to address it.  Someone has [suggested using jekyll-link-attributes](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank/issues/54#issuecomment-1298899325) instead.